# Passing data to destination UITableViewCell with identifier returns nil if table is not reloaded?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Can anyone explain why this returns nil for "destinationCell"

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToCreateTask" {
        let contact = contactList[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row]

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CreateTaskVC

        if let destinationCell = destinationVC.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("assignToCell") as? UITableViewCell {
            destinationCell.textLabel?.text = contact.contactName
            destinationCell.detailTextLabel?.text = contact.contactEmail
        }
    }
}
```

while this returns the correct "destinationCell"

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToCreateTask" {
        let contact = contactList[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row]

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CreateTaskVC

        **destinationVC.tableView.reloadData()**

        if let destinationCell = destinationVC.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("assignToCell") as? UITableViewCell {
            destinationCell.textLabel?.text = contact.contactName
            destinationCell.detailTextLabel?.text = contact.contactEmail
        }
    }
}
```

and if adding .reloadData() is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You shouldn't populate the tableview cell in the destination VC - rather, set a contact property and let the destination vc manage the table update.

Comment: I'm quite new to Swift - would you be able to provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

What the heck are you doing ?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        ...
        if let destinationCell = destinationVC.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("assignToCell") as? UITableViewCell {
            destinationCell.textLabel?.text = contact.contactName
            destinationCell.detailTextLabel?.text = contact.contactEmail
        }
```

The `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` function should *only* be used in a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, when populating your `UITableView`.

If you need your `prepareForSegue` function (or any other function) to get at data  in the cell which the user's tapped on, you should handle this in a `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function.

When this gets called, you'll have the `NSIndexPath` parameter, telling you the section and row index of the cell which was tapped, and you can lookup your data from there.

Store this "selected item" record in a `contact` variable, and when the `prepareForSegue` function gets called, you'll have `contact` value, ready to go !

Comment: The problem is that I already have the values that I want from this view via this line of code - 
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToCreateTask" {
        let contact = contactList[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row] -

I want to be able to change the properties of a tableview cell in the destination view controller.